# int execle(const char *path, const char *arg, ..., char * const envp[]);

Tags: linux

```c
int execle(const char *path, const char *arg, ..., char * const envp[]);
```

In the prototype of function above used in Linux, after variable arguments, they used named variable which is not possible in C language. 
Because in C language in variadic function after variable argument we can not pass named argument then why in function given above they used named argument after variable argument (`...`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The final argument is technically part of the variable argument list (`...`).  It is just shown to provide the type and a name for the final argument, to make the documentation easier to understand.  The [current version](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) of the manual page shows this argument in a comment to match the actual C prototype.